# Loops with ifelse() statement to create conditional variable in an existing data frame

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am trying to use a loop to create a new variable in an existing data frame that is conditional on the values of the variables included in the loop. The logic makes sense to me but I am getting unexpected results.

Take the following data frame as an example:

```
> df
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    0    1    0    1
2    1    0    0    1
3    1    1    0    1
4    0    0    1    0
5    0    1    1    0
```

I want to create a new variable (var5) that is equal to 0 if any of vars1-4 are equal to 1. Otherwise, I want this variable to be coded as a missing value. I wrote the following loop:

```
for (var in c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")) {
  df$var5 <- ifelse(
    df[, var] == 1, 0, NA
  )
}
```

This logic seems straightforward to me, as is similar to a "foreach" loop in Stata, but my results are unexpected:

```
> for (var in c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")) {
+   df$var5 <- ifelse(
+     df[, var] == 1, 0, NA
+   )
+ }
> df
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1    0    1    0    1    0
2    1    0    0    1    0
3    1    1    0    1    0
4    0    0    1    0   NA
5    0    1    1    0   NA
```

For some reason, the loop seems to only be applying the conditional statement to the last element of "var". Observations 4 and 5 should be be 0, given that those rows contain a one in the list of vars specified.

I'm sure there is something simple I am missing, but does anyone know how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each pass of your loop, you are overwriting the results from the previous pass, so `var1` through `var3` are wasted.

Based on your logic, I suggest `rowSums` and a test. You say that the value of `var5` should be a `0` if any of `var1:var4` are `1`, else it should be `NA`, so

```r
df$var5 <- ifelse(rowSums(df == 1) > 0, 0, NA)
df
#   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
# 1    0    1    0    1    0
# 2    1    0    0    1    0
# 3    1    1    0    1    0
# 4    0    0    1    0    0
# 5    0    1    1    0    0
```

If there are other columns in `df` that you do not want considered in this logic, then we can instead do

```r
df$var5 <- ifelse(rowSums(subset(df, select = var1:var4) == 1) > 0, 0, NA)
```

---

If you must use a `for` loop (discouraged), then you need to include the previous results in your logic.

```r
df$var5 <- NA
for (V in c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")) {
  df$var5 <- ifelse(!is.na(df$var5) | df[[V]] == 1, 0, NA)
}
df
#   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
# 1    0    1    0    1    0
# 2    1    0    0    1    0
# 3    1    1    0    1    0
# 4    0    0    1    0    0
# 5    0    1    1    0    0
```

Comment: This is a nice and logical solution. If I were hard-headed and determined to do this using a loop though, is there no way to easily re-write the original loop to produce the same result? My motivation is that I am trying to conceptually replicate Stata code to communicate with a collaborator, and the loop would be more analogous to the coding language they have used.

Comment: I edited in a (discouraged) `for` loop that includes the existing value of `var5` in its (re)assignment. Does that help understand the needed logic?

Comment: As an aside, if you're hoping to learn R as a replacement for your stata workflow, an immediate goal is to replicate the stata techniques, but the efficiencies in the two will be different: I encourage you to use this method initially but soon you may benefit more from learning the canonical way of doing things in R. For example, `for` loops are generally not the fastest way to deal with many operations in R.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense and actually seems to follow the Stata logic more closely. I'm more comfortable in R, which is probably why I haven't used loops very often in the past. Surprised to see how commonly they are used in Stata. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74327767/loops-with-ifelse-statement-to-create-conditional-variable-in-an-existing-data#comment131220266_74327850), here is how you could solve your problem:

```
df$var5 = NA
for(var in c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")) {
  df[df[[var]]==1, "var5"] = 0
}

  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1    0    1    0    1    0
2    1    0    0    1    0
3    1    1    0    1    0
4    0    0    1    0    0
5    0    1    1    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other options:

```r
library(tidyverse)

#data used
df <- read_table("var1 var2 var3 var4
0    1    0    1
1    0    0    1
1    1    0    1
0    0    1    0
0    1    1    0")

#tidyverse
df |>
  mutate(var5 = `+`(!if_any(var1:var4, \(x) x == 1)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     0     1     0     1     0
#> 2     1     0     0     1     0
#> 3     1     1     0     1     0
#> 4     0     0     1     0     0
#> 5     0     1     1     0     0

#base
df$var5 <- apply(df[,1:4], c(1), \(x) `+`(!any(x == 1)))
df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     0     1     0     1     0
#> 2     1     0     0     1     0
#> 3     1     1     0     1     0
#> 4     0     0     1     0     0
#> 5     0     1     1     0     0
```